# More than 24 hr format issue in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

I am picking the csv file from a folder which has a time field of more than 24 hours(format->[h]:MM:SS). But when I am using power query(not Power BI) time format is getting changed.

Eg: In my source file I have time as 46:33:10 but in power query it is loading as 1/2/1904 10:33:10 PM.

Now, I want 46:33:10 to be loaded/converted in my power query. I am not using Power BI to use any DAX Query. I have also tried converting it to Duration but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Power Query expects duration text to be formatted as `d.hh:mm:ss` where `hh < 24`, so it doesn't like 46 hours.

You can load the column as text and then write a transformation to convert it yourself.

Here's a sample query you can paste into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjG2Mja2MjRQitWJVjKyMjSyMjZRio0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [DurationText = _t]),
    #"Transform Column" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"DurationText", each let hours = Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":")) in #duration(Number.IntegerDivide(hours,24), Number.Mod(hours,24),0,0) + Duration.FromText("0.00:" & Text.AfterDelimiter(_,":"))}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transform Column",{{"DurationText", type duration}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The transformation function is this part:

```
each
    let
        hours = Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":"))
    in
        #duration(
            Number.IntegerDivide(hours, 24),
            Number.Mod(hours, 24),
            0,
            0
        ) + Duration.FromText("0.00:" & Text.AfterDelimiter(_,":"))
```

Basically, it splits the text on the first colon, converts the first part (hours) into days, hours and preserves the rest then combines it back into a single duration by adding the pieces together.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I am new to power query and I was able to figure Advance Editor and placed the code you have provided. But for Transformation function I have created new function(Right click->Create new function) and added that transformation code there.Am I right?

Comment: You can define it as a separate function if you'd like but you don't need to. I expanded out a piece of the query for better readability (it's part of the sample query).